# Postgres: INSERT INTO using Sequence on column

Tags: postgresql

Given that I have the following create syntax for postgres

```
CREATE TABLE CusGoals(
  biRecipientId BIGINT Default 0, 
  iEnvironment SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoal01 SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoal02 SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoal03 SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoal04 SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoal05 SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoal06 SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoal07 SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoal08 SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoal09 SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoal10 SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoal11 SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoal12 SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoal13 SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoal14 SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoal15 SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoal16 SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoal17 SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iGoalsId INTEGER Default 0, 
  iHealthWellness SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iInclusion SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iPeople SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iPlanet SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iResponsibleConsumption SMALLINT Default Null, 
  iSustainableInfrastructure SMALLINT Default Null, 
  tsCreated TIMESTAMPTZ, 
  tsLastModified TIMESTAMPTZ
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CusGoals_id ON CusGoals(iGoalsId);      
INSERT INTO CusGoals (iGoalsId) VALUES (0);
```

-- Log: Creating sequence 'auto_cusgoals_seq' for 'cus:goals'.

```
SELECT CreateSequenceIfNecessary('auto_cusgoals_seq', '1000', 'cache 30');
```

If I have the following insert statement

```
INSERT INTO CusGoals (iGoal01,iGoal04,iGoal14,iPlanet,iPeople,iInclusion,iResponsibleConsumption) VALUES (2,3,4,44,56,5,4)
```

How can I use the auto_cusgoals_seq on the iGoalsId to update correctly as I am getting the following error.

> PGS-220000 PostgreSQL error: ERROR: duplicate key value violates
> unique constraint "cusgoals_id" DETAIL: Key (igoalsid)=(0) already
> exists. WDB-200001 SQL statement 'INSERT INTO CusGoals
> (iGoal01,iGoal04,iGoal14,iPlanet,iPeople,iInclusion,iResponsibleConsumption)
> VALUES (2,3,4,44,56,5,4)' could not be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new sequence must be bumped to the current max value.

You  can reset it using

```sql
SELECT setval('auto_cusgoals_seq', max(igoalsid)) FROM CusGoals;
```

Comment: Thanks, i got it working like this also; `  var sqlSyntax = "INSERT INTO CusGoals (igoalsid, "+stringColumns+") VALUES (nextval('auto_cusgoals_seq'),"+stringValues+")";`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that biRecipientId is your primary key, just alter the data format from bigint to serial.

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/

Comment: my application does not allow such configuration  on the schema creation and I dont have access to the db directly.